# Any shorter code for drawing this in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Are there any possible shorter codes of drawing this diagram, maybe using `graphs` but it is not a regular polygon, or shortening the repetitive `\draw` in my code:

```
%% filename henry3.pgf
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%styles and libraries
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows}
\tikzstyle{mdar}=[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]
\tikzstyle{mdad}=[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}]
\tikzstyle{point}=[node distance=2cm, inner sep=0pt, fill=black, circle]
%nodes
\node[point] (p1) {.} ;
\node[point, below of = p1] (p2) {.}; 
\node[point, below of = p2, yshift=0.7cm](p3){.};
\node[point, below of = p3, yshift=0.4cm](p4){.};
\node[point, below of = p4, yshift=0.7cm](p5){.}; 
%%
\node[point, right of=p1, yshift=-1.4cm](p10){.};
\node[point, left of=p1, yshift=-1.4cm](p11){.};
\node[point, right of=p4,  xshift=-0.3cm] (p40) {.};
\node[point,left of=p4, xshift=0.3cm] (p41) {.};
%% there is a way of importing tikz's graph library and making things
%%easier and compressed but importing this does not work on my
 %%computer
%joining nodes
\draw[mdar](p1) -- (p11) ;\draw[mdar](p1) -- (p10);\draw[mdar] (p1) -- (p41);\draw[mdar] (p1) -- (p40);\draw[mdar](p1) -- (p2);
\draw[mdar](p2) -- (p11); \draw[mdar](p2) -- (p3);\draw[mdar](p2) -- (p10); \draw[mdar](p2) -- (p40); \draw[mdar](p2) -- (p41);
\draw[mdad](p11) -- (p3); \draw[mdad](p11) -- (p4); \draw[mdad](p11) -- (p5); \draw[mdar](p11) -- (p41);
\draw[mdar] (p10) -- (p3); \draw[mdad] (p10) -- (p4); \draw[mdad] (p10) -- (p5); \draw[mdar] (p10) -- (p40);
\draw[mdar](p3) -- (p4); \draw[mdar](p3) -- (p41); \draw[mdar](p3) -- (p40);
\draw[mdar](p4) -- (p41); \draw[mdar](p4) -- (p40); \draw[mdar](p4) -- (p5);
\draw[mdar](p40) -- (p5); \draw[mdar](p41) -- (p5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: If you can describe the algorithm used for deciding which points to connect tun you could code that. Alternatively use a `\foreach` loop and list the pairs for connections to be made to each node. That will at least make the code easier to read.

Comment: A full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) would be good!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know much about graphs so I won't attempt to use the graph libraries but you can renumber your nodes bit more meaningfully and then do a typical adjacency matrix approach.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[mdar/.style={
    decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
    postaction={decorate}
    },
mdad/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, 
             postaction={decorate}},
point/.style={node distance=2cm, inner sep=0pt, fill=black, circle}]

\node[point] (p1) {.} ;
\node[point, left of=p1, yshift=-1.4cm](p2){.};
\node[point, below of = p1] (p3) {.}; 
\node[point, right of=p1, yshift=-1.4cm](p4){.};
\node[point, below of = p3, yshift=0.7cm](p5){.};
\node[point, below of = p5, yshift=0.4cm](p7){.};
\node[point,left of=p7, xshift=0.3cm] (p6) {.};
\node[point, right of=p7,  xshift=-0.3cm] (p8) {.};
\node[point, below of = p7, yshift=0.7cm](p9){.}; 
\def\myadjmat{%
{0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1},
{0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1},
{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1},
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0},
}

\foreach \x[count=\xi] in \myadjmat{
  \foreach \y[count=\yi] in \x{
    \ifnum1=\y\relax\draw[mdar] (p\xi) -- (p\yi);\fi
  }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I got bored after the fifth but you get the idea. Also don't leave the `\usetikzlibrary{...}` commands in the picture. Instead carry them to your preamble. Finally you might consider skipping the `\tikzstyle` command as it is deprecated as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

Comment: Nice solution (+1), but I cant see  where you use `mdad` style. And by the way, all nodes have the same style ... so it can be defined as `every node/.style = {...}` and later at nodes dropped the style name :-)

Comment: @Zarko Frankly, I didn't bother

Comment: Is there some reason why `else` part of the `ifnum` was used?

Comment: @AJN it doesn't have any else part. `\relax` is to signal TeX to stop looking for numbers further

Comment: Thanks. I had wrongly assumed that the first command after the number was the `if` part and the second command was the `else` part.

Comment: Wow, need to go back and learn to draw using matrix approach cos we're definitely going to draw more stuff like this. Thanks too for the PoA :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example with the graph drawing stuff. The node positioning is not amazing, but can be changed fairly easily. It can be complied "as usual" with `pdflatex` (or `xelatex`, or `latex -> dvipdfm`, etc).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,decorations.markings}
\tikzgraphsset{on edge arrow/.style={/tikz/every edge/.append style={
  -, draw, postaction={
  decoration={markings, mark=at position \arrowpos with {\arrow{stealth}}},
  decorate}}}, > pos/.store in=\arrowpos, > pos=0.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]
\foreach \p [count=\i] in {(0,0),(-2,-1),(0,-1.75),(2,-1),(0,-3),
    (-1.5,-4.5),(0,-4.5),(1.5,-4.5),(0,-6.25)}
  \node [shape=circle, inner sep=0, minimum size=2,fill] (\i) at \p {};
\graph [use existing nodes, on edge arrow]{
    1 -> {2, 3, 4};
    2 -> {5 -> {6, 7, 8}, 6, 7 -> 9};
    3 -> {2, 4 -> {5, 7, 8}, 5};
    1 ->[> pos=.45] {6, 8};
    3 ->[> pos=.45] {6, 8};
    {2, 4} ->[> pos=0.66] 9;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Xrobot actually by removing one unnecessary library it works without `lualatex`.

Answer (score 5):

Since your arrows have no regular pattern, it's hard to make a really concise code because there is not an actual rule that governs where the arrows should go to, and so on. So This is a slightly longer code than I wanted to write, but it's still pretty short.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows}

\tikzset{
    %mdar/.style={very thin,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow{stealth reversed}}}, postaction={decorate}},
    mdad/.style={very thin,decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow[scale=.8]{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}},
    point/.style={inner sep=.5pt, fill=black, circle}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Nodes
\foreach \points [count=\xi] in {
        (0,0),
        (-1,1),(0,1),(1,1),
        (0,2),
        (-1.2,3.3),(0,3),(1.2,3.3),
        (0,4)}{
    \node[point] (p\xi) at \points {};
}

% Arrows
\foreach \name/\dest in {%  
    2/{1},
    3/{1,2,4},
    4/{1},
    5/{2,3,4},
    6/{1,2,3,5},
    7/{2,4,5,6,8},
    8/{1,3,4,5},
    9/{2,4,6,7,8},
    }{%
    \foreach \ppp in \dest{
        \draw[very thin, mdad] (p\name) -- (p\ppp);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```